Ubuntu upgrade changed my home directory permissions - malicious or mistake?
My setup
I have a private server (Ubuntu 22.04.4) that I use as a test server for my web development code.

Every couple of weeks I update it (sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade -y). I don't usually pay attention to what got updated.
My server sits behind a firewall and is supposed to be only accessible from specific IPs

Update broke ssh connectivity
Yesterday (7/10/2024), after the update process ran from my remote client (I am not sure what got updated or even if the update was successful or not), I noticed that I couldn't ssh into the server using public key authentication.
Upon some investigation, I realized that the permissions on my home directory got changed to +w for group and others.
Was it malicious?
I am trying to figure out if that change was malicious or simply some misconfigured update script. Is it possible for me to figure out the answer from any logs or something?
Is it such a common occurrence that I shouldn't even worry about it?
Edit 7/12/24
Here are the apt logs I found in /var/log/apt/term.log
(I should point out that the timing of apt upgrade could simply be a coincidence. I don't know for a fact that's what changed the permissions on my home directory)
Log started: 2024-07-10  06:18:56
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(R>Preparing to unpack .../0-python3.10-dev_3.10.12-1~22.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10-dev (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libpython3.10-dev_3.10.12-1~22.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-dev:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-libpython3.10_3.10.12-1~22.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-python3.10_3.10.12-1~22.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.12-1~22.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-python3.10-minimal_3.10.12-1~22.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.12-1~22.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.3) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) ...
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) ...
Setting up libpython3.10:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) ...
Setting up python3.10 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-dev:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) ...
Setting up python3.10-dev (3.10.12-1~22.04.4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Log ended: 2024-07-10  06:18:58

Here are some journal logs. I've included two sessions when I was able to login using ssh public key. Then the first time I wasn't able to. Something changed my home directory permissions between these two login attempts.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver sshd[13405]: Accepted publickey for phillup from 192.168.1.35 port 50152 ssh2: RSA SHA256:OFHAbXVTzYXGbhQyyL76BIalNJWSZYgW7HgP0Slx04w
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver sshd[13405]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user phillup(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd-logind[871]: New session 382 of user phillup.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user phillup(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[13413]: Exec binary '/usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher' does not exist: No such file or directory
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[13413]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-at\x2dspi\x2ddbus\x2dbus@autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Queued start job for default target Main User Target.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Created slice User Application Slice.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Reached target Paths.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Reached target Timers.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Reached target Sockets.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Reached target Basic System.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Reached target Main User Target.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Startup finished in 81ms.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:48:47 linuxserver systemd[1]: Started Session 382 of User phillup.
Jul 10 16:49:32 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:51:40 linuxserver sshd[13470]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.35 port 50152:11: disconnected by user
Jul 10 16:51:40 linuxserver sshd[13470]: Disconnected from user phillup 192.168.1.35 port 50152
Jul 10 16:51:40 linuxserver sshd[13405]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user phillup
Jul 10 16:51:40 linuxserver systemd[1]: session-382.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:51:40 linuxserver systemd-logind[871]: Session 382 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jul 10 16:51:40 linuxserver systemd-logind[871]: Removed session 382.
Jul 10 16:51:43 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Finished Exit the Session.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[13408]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Jul 10 16:51:50 linuxserver systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:52:25 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:54:31 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:54:31 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:54:52 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:55:01 linuxserver CRON[13501]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Jul 10 16:55:01 linuxserver CRON[13502]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 10 16:55:01 linuxserver CRON[13501]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver sshd[13507]: Accepted publickey for phillup from 192.168.1.35 port 50154 ssh2: RSA SHA256:OFHAbXVTzYXGbhQyyL76BIalNJWSZYgW7HgP0Slx04w
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver sshd[13507]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user phillup(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd-logind[871]: New session 385 of user phillup.
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd[13510]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user phillup(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[13515]: Exec binary '/usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher' does not exist: No such file or directory
Jul 10 16:56:28 linuxserver systemd-xdg-autostart-generator[13515]: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-at\x2dspi\x2ddbus\x2dbus@autostart.service, error parsing Exec= line: No such file or directory
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Queued start job for default target Main User Target.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Created slice User Application Slice.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Reached target Paths.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Reached target Timers.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Reached target Sockets.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Reached target Basic System.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Reached target Main User Target.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Startup finished in 81ms.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[1]: Started Session 385 of User phillup.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver sshd[13572]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.35 port 50154:11: disconnected by user
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver sshd[13572]: Disconnected from user phillup 192.168.1.35 port 50154
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver sshd[13507]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user phillup
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd[1]: session-385.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd-logind[871]: Session 385 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jul 10 16:56:29 linuxserver systemd-logind[871]: Removed session 385.
Jul 10 16:56:34 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Stopped target Basic System.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Stopped target Paths.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Stopped target Sockets.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Reached target Shutdown.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Finished Exit the Session.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[13510]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000...
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: run-user-1000.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/1000.
Jul 10 16:56:39 linuxserver systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Jul 10 16:56:50 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:57:03 linuxserver sshd[13580]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/phillup
Jul 10 16:57:08 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 10 16:57:08 linuxserver systemd-networkd[835]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.


@Ja1024, yes permissions were 777 after the update. SSH doesn't authenticate if you have 777 permissions on the home directory.

Welcome to the community. That's pretty odd, but I'm afraid we need more information and logs

Thank you @SirMuffington. What logs would be helpful to see?

Perhaps which packages got updated? Apt is pretty good about logging that. Also, look for any notable logs in the journal perhaps.

SSHDaemon does not permit login to potentially compromised users if Strictmode has been enabled (the default)
See this snippet of the man page:

StrictModes
Specifies whether sshd(8) should check file modes and ownership of the user's files and home directory before accepting   login.
This is normally desirable because novices sometimes accidentally leave their directory or files world-writable.
The default is yes.
Note: that this does not apply to ChrootDirectory, whose permissions and ownership are checked unconditionally.

It mainly concerns with the permissions of the ~/.ssh and the keys within them.
As for what package caused the erroneous permission to be set, we need more information.
I would advise against disabling Strict mode as it protects you from many stupid mistakes.

Thank you for sharing your knowledge. It's correct technical information, but it's a little bit of a non sequitur.

Firstly, I made the comment while it was on the InfoSec stack exchange. Where the second part is out of scope, but this first part isn’t.
Secondly, the cause of the behavior of SSH Daemon is not a non sequitur…. It’s 1 part of the problem. Maybe instead of presuming something does not follow (which is what a non sequitur is) actually know the history of a post and see how it got to where it is.
